# Doyxgen onetime macro expansion / expansion command

Tags: macros, doxygen, preprocessor, code-documentation, variable-expansion

I have some code like the following example:

```c
/** @file HelloPi.c */

/** The definition of pi */
#define PI 3.1415

/** @brief The main function.
 *  @details Prints the value of #PI, which is actual defined as 3.1415. */
void main()
{
  printf("The value of pi is %f\n",PI);
}
```

In my doxygen dokumentation I would like to to have NO macro expansion for PI (and other defines) in general.
But on one paragraph in the documentation I need the value of pi (e.g. @details description of the main function).

Is there any possibility to expand the macro at this single part of documentation with a command or something? Something like `/** @details ...the value of #PI is $(PI).*/`

I only know the build-in MACRO_EXPANSION tag which works for the whole documentation: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html :-/

Thanks for help :)
Jan

Edit:
Add an other example which maybe better describes my Problem:

```c
/** @file ErrorHandling.c */


#define ERR_CODE_POWERUNIT 1001 ///< Error in power unit */
            /** @page errors
             *  [value of ERR_CODE_POWERUNIT ] means \copybrief ERR_CODE_POWERUNIT */

void errHandler(int error)
{
  if(error=ERR_CODE_POWERUNIT)
    printf("Error %d occur\n",ERR_CODE_POWERUNIT);
}
```

In the documentation I would like to have:
"1001 means Error in power unit"

Comment: Which version of doxygen?

Comment: Version is 1.18.13 (debian LTS Version) but an Update to 1.9.1 would be possible.

Comment: Certainly advised to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In doxygen there is no possibility to do a conversion of a predefined variable (only) in the documentation.
You used in your documentation the  an environment variable `$(PI)` but ths is quite cumbersome as you have to st the environment variable each time.

A better solution would be to use an `ALIASES` like:

```
ALIASES += pi=3.1415
```

or

```
ALIASES +\= "The value of PI = 3.14159265359..."
```

with which you define a command `\pi` that can be used in the documentation and will be replaced with the text / commands in the alias.

```
/** @details ...the value of #PI is \pi.*/
```

would result in something like (by head:

```
  ...the value of #PI is 3.1415
```

Comment: Hi Albert, when I use the alias I always refer to the value in the config file and not to the one in the code. So I need to define my macro in source AND in the config. Another example: PI is not pi, but an error code which is shown to the user: In the code I have `#define POWER_ERROR 1001` and use the macro in the code. But the user only get the 1001. Would be great to get the documentation that 1001 means 'error in the power-unit'.

Comment: Indeed I forgot to mention that you have to double the information (I thought about it but forgot to write it down). I don't get the second part of the comment yet, the text 'error in the power-unit' must be available as well, , so why not adding it to the ALIASES as well like `ALIASES += err_1001="1001 i.e. error in the power unit"` or `ALIASES += err_1001="error in the power unit"` and use in the documentation `\err_1001`

Comment: Yes would be an possibility. Anyway you need to write it twice. Once in code once somewehere else. I think I will go the following way: ``` /** @page errors 1001 means \copybrief ERR_CODE_POWERUNIT */ ``` (example above). everything is at one place / file.The only thing to do is writing '1001' per hand into the doc page. So copy&paste for other error codes will need a little bit of attention :) but other developers don't need to look in different files. Maybe the easiest way.

Comment: Thank you for helping, Albert! :)

Comment: The solution with copybrief for the text looks quite valid. Thinking about it qyou might also be successful wilt `ALIASES +="ERR{1}="\1 means \copybrief ERR_CODE_\1` and use in the docu: `\ERR{1001}`

Comment: Seems to be a good way! Thank you very much for the quick support! I marked this post as the preferred answer.